# How to send func name as arg with inline loop in python

Tags: python, qt, generator

I'm working on a GUI program and i have two `QCheck` widgets and want to connect them both to a single function. every thing is fine with a code like this:

```
widgets = [widget1,widget2]
for widget in widgets:
    self.connect(widget, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.TheFunction)
```

I know it might be very lazy but it must be a way for doing this in a single line way! I'm aware that I can use lambda but is there any way I can make it work like this?

```
self.connect((x for x in (widget1,widget2)), SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.TheFunction)
```

both `widget1` and `widget2` are `QObject`s and this is what the `connect` expect to see. but no matter what i try it always tell me that the arguments are not `QObject`!

Comment: Why would you want to put that into a single line? I would recommend leaving it as written. The problem with the generator you tried to write for this is that you're passing in a generator as the first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write simple `for` loop in one line

```
for x in (widget1, widget2): self.connect(x, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.TheFunction)
```

If you need to use list comprehension then rather

```
list(self.connect(x, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.TheFunction) for x in (widget1,widget2))
```

or

```
[self.connect(x, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.TheFunction) for x in (widget1,widget2)]
```

(thanks Jean-François Fabre)

but your first version in 3 lines is more readable.

Comment: in the second case, you have to consume the generator function or nothing is executed!

Comment: oh this is beautiful. instead of feeding the connect func from a list you put the whole func in a list. absolutely beautiful. thanks Furas, thanks Jean-Francois

Answer (score 1):

your code is already optimal. A good old loop is sometimes best, specially here where you don't do anything with the return value of `connect` (not creating a generator function or a list).

If you *really* want a oneliner let me suggest:

```
for widget in [widget1,widget2]: self.connect(widget, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.TheFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

The readability of the code can be greatly improved by using [new-style signal and syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), and putting each connection on its own line:

```
widget1.clicked.connect(self.TheFunction)
widget2.clicked.connect(self.TheFunction)
```

I suppose you could also do a one-liner like this:

```
for widget in widget1, widget2: widget.clicked.connect(self.TheFunction)
```

but that looks far less readable to me.

Comment: i'm using PyQt4 and unfortunately it's not working. thanks i will use it in version 5.

Comment: @Babakslt. It works perfectly fine in PyQt4 - unless you're using a very, very old version of it (i..e. before version 4.5).